# Is it possible to compute projective transformation from correspondences?

Tags: computer-vision, linear-algebra

I am trying to compute the projective transformation for each plane in the following object.

[image]

The goal is to map this reference object to the target plane.
[image]

Therefore, each plane can generate 9 correspondences. I successfully generated a least square SVD solution, but this mapping does not fit the geometry.
[image]

I wonder is it possible to compute the projective transformation from these information?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Actually only 4 point correspondences are necessary. I am not completely sure, since you did not provide code, but is there a chance that you assumed just an affine transformation (3x3 matrix with [0, 0, 1] as a last row). That would not be sufficient.

Take a look over [here](http://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/) for a good step by step solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, the result was algebraically correct. I didn't fixed the last row. It was just that the SVD solution was not geometrically meaningful. It took me a while to figure out this thing couldn't be solved with a linear system because forcing the norm of the solution |h| to be 1 and minimizing Ah is not an objective function to the true geometric mapping. A nonlinear optimization (may be basing on reprojection error) needs to be used to correct the initial solution. I'll update my solution later when I have time.

Comment: First of all, why do you compute this on your own? There are dozens of sophisticated solutions out there (see Link above). I am not sure if I get you right but this is solvable using a linear system. For example look [here](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/wi07/cse252a/homography_estimation/homography_estimation.pdf).

Comment: I understand. I am just curious how this is actually done. The link you gave is a common implementation that gets taught in class, but this will not work. By enforcing |x| = 1 while minimizing dot(Ax, Ax) is not an objective function to minimize reprojection error. You can compare the result generated by findHomography in OpenCV and that using SVD.